# C++11 type deduce with asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, typedef

I am using `boost::asio::steady_timer _timer`, but I found if using -std=c++11 flag, compiler will report error of can not convert type at:

```
boost::asio::steady_timer::time_point now() {
    return boost::asio::steady_timer::clock_type::now();
}
```

and no match function for operator+() at:

```
_timer.expires_at(now()+boost::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```

It seems the compiler can not deduce the correct type in c++11 mode. But instead I using

```
boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<boost::chrono::steady_clock> _timer;
```

and change `boost::asio::steady_timer::time_point` 
to
 `boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point`

It is OK. However, they are same thing and work fine in g++ without 0x or 11 mode.

Is C++11 do something different thing about typedef deduce? Or a boost config problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `basic_waitable_timer` class can work with `std::chrono` or `boost::chrono`. On a recent g++, it uses `std::chrono` by default. To force using `boost::chrono`, define `BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_STD_CHRONO`.

This is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/chrono.html)